# How to omit the last row of the resultant array if number of rows are odd in php?

Tags: php

i have a mysql table in the following format

```
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | event_id | event_type | machine    | user      |  timeStamp          | Shift   | Reason             | Count |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 101      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 01:03:55 | Shift1  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 102      | Up         | Machine2   | operator2 | 2012-09-06 01:03:55 | Shift1  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 103      | Up         | Machine3   | operator3 | 2012-09-06 01:03:55 | Shift1  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 104      | Down       | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 02:03:55 | Shift1  | Break Down         | 1     |
    | 101      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 02:33:55 | Shift1  | After BD           | 1     |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

by passing the following query.

```
  $data = mysql_query("select * from rpt_machine_log where (timestamp between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK) and now() && (machine='machine$i') && (shift='Shift1') ) AND (reason='Start of The Shift' OR reason='End of Shift') ORDER BY 'even_id'")
```

i get the following output

```
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | event_id | event_type | machine    | user      |  timeStamp          | Shift   | Reason             | Count |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 101      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 01:03:55 | Shift1  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 118      | Down       | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 06:00:55 | Shift1  | End of The shift   | 1     |
    | 127      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-07 01:03:55 | Shift1  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 148      | Down       | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-07 02:03:55 | Shift1  | End of The shift   | 1     |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I calculate Total Shift Time by finding the difference of the End of The shift and Star of The shift like the following code.

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shifttime{$i})) 
            {
                if(isset($timestamp))
                {
                    $diff_shift_time{$i}= strtotime($row['timestamp']) - strtotime($timestamp);
                    $diff_shift_time_array{$i}[]=$diff_shift_time{$i};
                    unset($timestamp);
                }
                else
                {
                    $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
                }
            }

            foreach ($diff_shift_time_array{$i} as &$value){
                $Total_shift_time{$i} += $value;
                }
```

in some cases the output of the query is as follows.

```
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | event_id | event_type | machine    | user      |  timeStamp          | Shift   | Reason             | Count |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 121      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 06:03:55 | Shift2  | Start of The shift | 1     |
    | 124      | Down       | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-06 01:00:55 | Shift2  | End of The shift   | 1     |
    | 151      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-09-07 06:03:55 | Shift2  | Start of The shift | 1     |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when i calculate the total shift time, i get negative value, because my resultant table ends with Up event.

Since the calculation is for consecutive up and down(`so the no of rows of the resultant row should always be even`), the last up doesn't have down event to perform calculation.

I want to delete the last row of the table if the row count is odd.

How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 $count = mysql_num_rows($shifttime{$i});
 $remove_last = $count%2==0?false:true;
 $cur_key = 0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shifttime{$i})) 
            {
                if(TRUE === $remove_last && $cur_key == ($count-1))
                      break;
                $cur_key++;

                if(isset($timestamp))
                {
                    $diff_shift_time{$i}= strtotime($row['timestamp']) - strtotime($timestamp);
                    $diff_shift_time_array{$i}[]=$diff_shift_time{$i};
                    unset($timestamp);
                }
                else
                {
                    $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you still getting negative number of rows?

Comment: No. but the time is displaying in negative

Comment: After adding the above code, the number of row in the result array is reduced to even. but the calculation of the difference in time gives me negative value as usual.

Comment: I guess it is because of the End of The shift time is less than Start of The shift time.

Comment: for shift1 its always fine. the output is like this.`Array ( [0] => 17820 [1] => 17820 ) Array ( [0] => 17820 [1] => 17820 ) Array ( [0] => 17820 [1] => 17820 )`. for shift2 `Array ( [0] => -86400 ) Array ( [0] => 68220 ) Array ( [0] => -86400 )`.

Comment: ah.. that was unneeded anymore. As you said, problem lies in timestamp column. Shift can't end before it starts, except if employee was fired

Comment: You have to correct 'timeStamp' row of 'rpt_machine_log' table where 'event_id' is 124. 
You have to input value even or bigger than '2012-09-06 06:03:55'.
If this table is used by some company and/or is important to someone, don't be hasty to change anything yourself. Discuss about it with other people who are related to that database

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of the array to see if the size is odd:

```
    if (sizeof($arr) % 2 == 1) { 
         // This array is odd sized.
         array_pop($arr); // Remove last element. 
    }
```

Comment: i tried like this `if (sizeof (mysql_fetch_assoc($shifttime{$i})) % 2 == 1) 
      { 
      // This array is odd sized.
      array_pop($shifttime{$i}); // Remove last element. 
      if(isset($timestamp))
      {
       $diff_shift_time{$i}= strtotime($row['timestamp']) - strtotime($timestamp);
       $diff_shift_time_array{$i}[]=$diff_shift_time{$i};
       unset($timestamp);
      }
      else
      {
       $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
      }
     }`. 
It is displaying as 0:0:0